# Is it possible to use python library chispa in a aws glue script

Tags: python, aws-glue

I need to validate the load of csv/parquet file from S3 to postgres. I got the dataframes from both sides. Need to do data integrity check.

I wish to use chispa library's assert_df_equality to do so.

Can I access chispa lib. from  my aws glue script?

I tried adding job parameter --additional_python_modules with value chispa-binary - did not work.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read, I think the value of the parameter should be ***chispa*** instead of ***chispa-binary***. Let me know if that solves it.
The rule of thumb that I go by for --additional_python_modules is that it's essential doing a pip install. When I looked up the chispa set up that's the value I saw. Here's some documentation on the parameter in Glue if curious. Keep me posted : )

[AWS Documentation](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/glue-version2-external-python-libraries)